# AJAX Request POST data to rails controller gives 404

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to post data to a rails controller via an AJAX request

My route: `get "pki_login/authenticate" => "pki_logins#authenticate"`

The JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/pki_login/authenticate',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      },
    data: passcode
});
```

then inside `pki_logins_controller.rb` i have:

```
def authenticate
  puts params[:passcode]
end
```

the `authenticate.html.erb` file just contains a `h3` tag.

I can visit /pki_login/authenticate and it works, but when accessing via AJAX I get a 404 so I don't even know if the POST works either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining a `get` route but making `POST` request.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/pki_login/authenticate',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      },
    data: passcode
});
```

Or change the route to `post` and use `post` ajax request as:

```
# config/routes.rb
post "pki_login/authenticate" => "pki_logins#authenticate"
```

Then the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/pki_login/authenticate',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      },
    data: passcode
});
```

Comment: And I believe one success method is enough

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, removed.

Comment: thank you @vee I'm swapped the success with error, woops! that worked but it triggers the 'error' callback. If I log the 'data' i get back from the error i get `Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Comment: @roly, you need to ensure that the action `authenticate` returns appropriate `json` response, as your ajax request is expecting `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: silly me, i was thinking datatype was what I was sending

Comment: this post solved my problem somehow. Use GET in routes and ajax call if you really return a page/partial. But use POST if you really only want to call a method without returning stuff like this.